# SQL Server linked server error locating server in sql server 2005

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server-2005, linked-server

When I execute query like this

> select * from openquery(XYZ, 'select * from patient')

I create the linked server in the SQL server 2005 and connect with the MYSQL and when I execute query and display errors like..

> OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI" for linked server "XYZ" returned message
>   "Login timeout expired".
>
> OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI" for linked server  "XYZ" returned message
>   "An error has occurred while establishing a
>   connection to the server. When connecting to SQL Server 2005, this
>   failure may be caused by the fact that under the default settings SQL
>   Server does not allow remote connections.". 
>   Msg 53, Level 16, State 1,
>   Line 0 Named Pipes Provider: 
>   Could not open a connection to SQL Server
>   [53].

Answer (score 2):

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/05/21/sql-server-fix-error-provider-named-pipes-provider-error-40-could-not-open-a-connection-to-sql-server-microsoft-sql-server-error/

i think this will help you...

Comment: in addition to this add the port of MySql in Firewall Exception. hope this will work.